# Cannot acces to gitlab on my own CentOS 7 server

Tags: gitlab

I've installed  gitlab on centos 7 and I can't access to the login page ,I think I could be  a problem with some port.In the server is installed apache too.

I've setted the external_url

```
external_url 'http://192.168.0.6:8082'
```

But when I try to access to that url ,the connection has timed out.
This is th output of netstat -tuplen command,I'm not an expert but is listening 8082 port.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      991        361214     -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9229          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      995        361078     -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9168          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      995        361198     -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8082            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          361124     -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9236          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      995        361102     -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17339      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18311      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          361125     -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6783            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      991        361018     -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9121          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      994        361340     -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      991        361347     -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9187          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      992        361240     -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9093          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      991        361025     -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8080                :::*                    LISTEN      995        362906     -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9168                :::*                    LISTEN      995        361197     -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          17844      -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8082                :::*                    LISTEN      995        362943     -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          17350      -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          18312      -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           997        14248      -
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                997        14249      -
```

What could be the problem??

Comment: Post results of "ip addr".  Could be firewalld or SELinux, but you are using a browser from the same CentOS desktop on 192.168.0.6?  What happens if you try http://127.0.0.1:8082 ?

Comment: I'm using  a browser in another computer on the same local network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be blocked by the firewall.  Run the command to list the current settings:

`firewall-cmd --list-all`

If the firewall is on but port 8082 is not open, allow it:

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8082/tcp`

The zone might be different.